# What do people understand by Masters in Chinese Studies

Tags: masters, china

I'm keen to find out what people understand by a Masters in "Chinese Studies" Is it China Studies? I.e. is it a catch-all social sciences area studies? Is it language? Is it culture?
I ask because I am setting up a new Masters at the University St Andrews in "Chinese Cultural Studies". It's a novel concept since it focuses on the Chinese-speaking world as a whole and not just China, and it is not multidisciplinary since it focuses on a cultural studies approach.
But I just wonder how people would go about searching for a Masters like that on the Internet?

Comment: I'd look around at other universities. Various programs in Near Eastern Studies, Middle Eastern Studies, Chinese Studies, ... Likely quite a mix of how they are constructed.

Comment: This could vary a lot between institutions and certainly from country to country.

Comment: But a search for a multidisciplinary program would probably include a lot of keywords, such as you have done here.